# line-up data in two colums of a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file like the one below

```
1,1  
2,2  
3,4  
4,5  
6,6
```

As you can see, "5" is missing from column 1, "3" is missing from column 2.
I would like to write a script that would allow me to compare both columns and insert "value missing". The output would look something like:

```
1,1  
2,2
3, value missing
4,4
value missing, 5
6,6
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Note: I used numbers in the example, the real problem has strings without any real meaning

Edit:
I included a sample of the actual data below

```
HM999993,HM999993  
HM999995,HM999995  
HM999997,HM999997  
J04353,J04353  
JF800658,JF834523  
JF834523,JF906559  
JF906559,JN171845  
JN171845,K02718  
JN709469,M12732  
JN709470,M12737  
JN709471,M14119  
JN709472,M17463  
JQ754321,M20219
```

Comment: Why don't you give us a sample of the actual data anyway. Are the left and right columns supposed to contain the same set of values, or are they unrelated?

Comment: ... also, I think your output lines are reversed - should have `value missing, 3` and `5, value missing`, not vice-versa.

Comment: if the lines are sorted [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) might help or [`diff`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) in a more general case. Columns in the input file are considered files for the utilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs further simplification, but I guess it works:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv

def navigation(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    prev = None
    item = iterator.next()

    for next in iterator:
        yield (prev, item, next)
        prev = item
        item = next

    yield (prev, item, None)

with open('input.csv') as csv_input:
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_output:
        old_data = []
        new_data = []

        for row in csv.reader(csv_input):
            old_data += row

        for index, (_prev, item, _next) in enumerate(navigation(old_data)):
            if _next != item:
                if _prev != item:
                    row = [item, 'missing value']
                    new_data.append(row if index % 2 == 0 else row[::-1])
            else:
                new_data.append([item, _next])

        writer = csv.writer(csv_output, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerows(new_data)
```

Comment: sweet! I believe this worked! Thanks Paulo (and everyone) for the help

Comment: @Stylize The best way to thank someone on SO is by [accepting their answer by clicking the checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) next to the answer. This rewards both of you with some rep points and marks this problem as solved.

Comment: @Stylize: Glad to know it worked out well. I've updated my code for better readability, hopefully this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather simple task using integers.  However, using strings would be more complicated.  With integers you can compare the two numbers and if one was higher than the other then you would know that there was a missing value.  This straight-forward comparison would not be available for strings, unless they were ordered alphabetically and you only had one string starting with each letter.

If you were to just compare the number of lines in each file to determine the total number of missing strings, then you would run into issues determining which position the missing strings were from, as requested in your question.

Comment: I agree, I used an example with integers to make the question more obvious. The problem using strings is a lot more complex. I am really at a loss on how to accomplish this

Comment: Aside from the alphabetical structure, an even number of strings starting with each letter, or an empty line for each missing value, I don't believe it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the full list of strings expected in each column, I don't think this can be solved. Otherwise,

```
import csv

expected_in_A = set(['a','b','c','d'])
expected_in_B = set(['w','x','y','z'])

def main():
    with open('myfile.csv', 'rb+') as f:
        incsv = csv.reader(f)
        for row in incsv:
            expected_in_A.discard(row[0])
            expected_in_B.discard(row[1])

        # because the file opening mode included '+',
        # and because we have already read to the end of it,
        # we can now simply append to it:
        outcsv = csv.writer(f)
        outcsv.writerows([val, 'value missing'] for val in expected_in_A)
        outcsv.writerows(['value missing', val] for val in expected_in_B)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

if `myfile.csv` contains

```
a,w
b,x
d,z
```

(with a carriage return following z!) then it becomes

```
a,w
b,x
d,z
c,value missing
value missing,y
```